# ABCPDF error on trying to create pdf

Tags: .net, abcpdf

I am using ABCPDF to generate PDF and I get the following error message when I call the AddImageUrl() method

[image]

any ideas? basically the application crashes and I am stuck with this. !

Any help gretaly appreciated.

Poornima

Answer (score 1):

iertutil.dll is used as a runtime utility by Internet Explorer.

As you may know, Internet Explorer is used by abcpdf to render the html before the pdf transformation.

( i'm not sure if it's always the case with the newer version of abcpdf though ).

With the information you provide, i can think of three things:

- Check if your Internet explorer version is compatible with your abcpdf version (IE update?)
- try to update your abcpdf version if you can
- Hosting your application with IIS may help? (wild guess but tuning the iis application pool parameters did solve some issue for me once)

Anyway you should provide your Internet Explorer version and your abcpdf version

Comment: This is the correct answer. acbPDF is very sensitive to mismatches in versions between abcPDF and IE. If IE is too new for the version of abcPDF, it will throw that error.

Comment: i am using IE9 and it seems like ABCPDF version 8 has support for IE9

Comment: On the other hand I have Adobe Reader XI installed and version 8.0 does not support for it. Could that be the cause